# print floats from audio input callback function

Tags: callback, recording, portaudio

I'm working on a university project that involves a lot of programming in C, especially with Portaudio & ALSA. At the moment i'm trying to make a callback function to pass audio through, standard input/output job. I was wondering if anybody could tell me how to print the floats from my inputBuffer to display in real time in the terminal? Here is the internal structure of my callback function so far.

Thanks very much for your help in advance!

```html
#define SAMPLE_RATE         (44100)
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE      paFloat32
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER   (64)

typedef float SAMPLE;


static int audio_callback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                         unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                         const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                         PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                         void *userData )
{
    SAMPLE *out = (SAMPLE*)outputBuffer;
    const SAMPLE *in = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    unsigned int i;
    (void) timeInfo; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if( inputBuffer == NULL )
    {
        
        for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
        {
            *out++ = *in++;    /* left  -  clean */
            *out++ = *in++;         /* right -  clean  */
        }
    }
    
    return paContinue;
}
```