# Interpreting inputBuffer's Value in a Callback

Tags: callback, portaudio

I am basing my code off of Portaudio's [paex_record_file.c](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record__file_8c_source.html) example. One of the parameters in the callback is inputBuffer, and I wanted to use its data to calculate other numbers with the double/float type. I changed the file from a .raw to a .txt, but notepad still cannot read it, leading me to believe its data is not actually encoded as a number. How is the data stored in inputBuffer and how can I do arithmetic with it (add, multiply, divide, etc)?

This is how I initialized inputParameters:

```
inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(); /* default input device */
if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default input device.\n");
    goto error;
}
inputParameters.channelCount = 2;                    /* stereo input */
inputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
```

This question is somewhat related to [print floats from audio input callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582899/print-floats-from-audio-input-callback-function) (unanswered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `inputBuffer` parameter to the callback is a `void*`. The actual type of the underlying buffer depends on the parameters and the flags that you pass to `Pa_OpenStream`.

If you specified `paFloat32` then there will be a `float*` in there somewhere. However the are two possibilities:

1. **Interleaved:** `inputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;`
2. **Non-Interleaved:** `inputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32|paNonInterleaved;`

You specified the *interleaved* option. In this case, `inputBuffer` points to a single buffer of interleaved floats. So you can write:

```
float *samples = (float*)inputBuffer;
```

In a two channel stream `samples` will contain interleaved left and right samples, e.g.:

```
samples[0]; // first left sample
samples[1]; // first right sample
samples[2]; // second left sample
samples[3]; // second right sample
// etc.
```

For completeness: If it had been a *non-interleaved* stream then `inputBuffer` points to an array of pointers to single-channel buffers. To extract the buffer pointers you would write something like:

```
float *left = ((float **) inputBuffer)[0];
float *right = ((float **) inputBuffer)[1];
```

Note that in all cases `framesPerBuffer` counts *frames* not samples. A frame includes one sample from each channel. For example, in a stereo stream, a frame includes both the left and right channel samples.

Comment: Thank you so much!